# Sum Visible Values of Column in RadGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a label in my form, I need to sum values of visible rows in a specific column of RadGrid and show the result in label. [Visible rows = Rows that are visible after and before filter.]

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadGridView has a ChildRows property which will give you the resulted collection of rows, after it si filtered. More info here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/rows/rows-vs-childrows